# How to "unshrink" objects in a stack view

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout, uikit, interface-builder

I am just getting started with Swift, and I am wondering how to 'unshrink' objects placed in a stack view. I have all these objects stacked in stack views (3 vertical and 1 horizontal, stacking the vertical ones).

[What I Have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5lGm.png)

However, I want the text fields to be far wider than that. I am not sure how to execute that as when I try and use the size inspector, it grays out the size editor. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest leaving the intrinsic size to default. Instead, add a width constraint to your `UITextField`s.

Comment: Is there a con to switching the intrinsic size off of default?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to correct stack view's distribution. Have a look at your stack view in atributes inspector. It should look something like this:

[image]

As you can see there are several properties there. Play around with  Alignment and Distribution. Those are the ones I think you need to change. The default values are both set to "Fill". I think you might need "Fill Proportionally".

Comment: Thanks. It turns out this isn't exactly what I need, though I found the solution. Under size inspector, I needed to switch intrinsic size from Default to Placeholder, which allows you to set it manually. Thanks anyways!